# VB .Net Sending email using Gmail account

Tags: vb.net, smtp, gmail

Why does this timeout?

```
Dim s As New SmtpClient
s.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
s.Port = 465
s.EnableSsl = True
s.Timeout = 5000
s.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("my.name@gmail.com", "mypassword")

Dim m As New MailMessage
m.To.Add("my.name@gmail.com")
m.From = New MailAddress("my.name@gmail.com")
m.Body = "Test Message"
m.Subject = "Test Subject"
s.Send(m)
```

These settings come straight from my Outlook Express test setup, and it can send fine.

Set really long timeout = does nothing

Change port numbers to 587 or 25 = does nothing

One thought: Outlook Express has a "My server requires authentication" option, which I couldn't see an obvious equivalent for with SmtpClient. Could it be related to that?

Thanks in advance

Dave

--Trindaz on Fedang #vb.net-smtp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: You might need to add the following line: `s.UseDefaultCredentials = False` before the line starting with `s.Credentials...`

Do you have a firewall or some kind of anti-virus program running that might be blocking the connections?

A good place to start is to just do a simple connect from the command line.

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 465
```

Note, depending on Windows version you might have to enable the telnet client first, see this [link](http://www.fettesps.com/windows-7-enable-telnet/) for details.

Comment: Now it gets weirder: s.UseDefaultCredentials = False 'kinda' works. The email gets through, but I still get a timeout error!

Using HyperTerminal to open smtp.gmail.com 465 got me a blank screen which I couldn't type on. Running telnet smtp.gmail.com 465 straight from the command line got me a black screen which only sorta worked - typing moved the cursor along but no characers appeared.

Comment: UPDATE: setting timeout to 10 seconds avoids the timeout too. Thanks ho1!

Answer (score -2):

You have to go into your gmail account and turn on access for less secure apps and change the port to 587